# How to update database automatically on webserver or host?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, webmin

is there way I can update my database automatically instead of adding information manually. my database is created in mysql workbench which is connected to mysql server via webmin.

Comment: You want to insert information in database or u want to update tables in ER model when u add new atributs?

Comment: Simple answer is YES. If you want further advice, then you would need to let us know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PaulF I want to connect my database to cctv camera which generates xml data which i want to be uploaded to database automatically.

Comment: The question you have asked is far to broad to get a proper response on SO - I am surprised you haven't been downvoted or the question blocked. You should decide on what language you would be using to collect the data - eg Java, C#, PHP - & then search for how to connect to MySQL using that. There will be many online tutorials. If you have problems following them - then post a specific question here, showing your attempts so far.

Comment: @PaulF the database which i created has xml data file which created in mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use Event Scheduler in Mysql

```
delimiter |
alter EVENT Your_event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-11-14 22:00:00' DO BEGIN 

    -- you query to update here
    update table1 set exported = 1 where exported is null;

   END |

delimiter ;
```

Make sure you set agent on

```
#set event agent on
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

More details Here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html